# How do I integrate Nvidia Ansel into my Unity game?

Tags: unity, nvidia, integration

I want to be able to use the super high resolution image capabilities that ansel have to offer but I don't know how to add it as the only thing that i can find are C++ libraries on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since November this year Nvidia have started releasing plugins as part of their partnership with Unity to [integrate Gameworks into the engine](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2016/11/01/nvidia-unity-vrworks-ansel/).

As of now there is a plugin available on the asset store that allows you to add support. Once you have it there is a pdf included in the plugin files that should help you with integrating it into your game.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/nvidia-ansel-74758

Since Unity and Nvidia are working together it wouldn't surprise me if they simply move all of the Gameworks stuff into the engine in a future release.